# How to shift a text in node.js

Tags: node.js

I remember there was a function in **node.js** named **shift** that worked like this:

```
"hello".shift(/*amount*/ 1)
```

and it gave "ello" but now it gives error

please tell me the function name or tell me if it even exists

Comment: `.shift()` is a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) on an Array.  It does not work on strings, but you can convert a string to an array of characters with [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and you could then use `.shift()` on that new array.  If you tell us what you're actually trying to do (show the input and desired output), we can better advise how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"Hello".substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `.shift(...)` is a prototype of `Array`.

An alternative function is to use this function:

```js
function Shift(text) {
  var arr = text.split("");
  arr.shift();
  var originalString = arr.join("");
  return originalString;
}
```